# Netflix not working in my chromium browser fork

Tags: browser, chromium, drm, netflix, widevine

I want to make a chromium fork which can play Netflix.

I have made some chromium based browsers and I have enabled widevine in them and this sites says widevine works https://www.visualon.com/index.php/html5-player-drm-demo/

I modified `chrome/browser/component_updater/registration.cc` and commented some lines like this to enable widevine like this

```
// #if BUILDFLAG(ENABLE_MEDIA_FOUNDATION_WIDEVINE_CDM)
#include "chrome/browser/component_updater/media_foundation_widevine_cdm_component_installer.h"
// #endif

// #if BUILDFLAG(ENABLE_WIDEVINE_CDM_COMPONENT)
#include "chrome/browser/component_updater/widevine_cdm_component_installer.h"
// #endif  // BUILDFLAG(ENABLE_WIDEVINE_CDM_COMPONENT)
```

After that spotify, Netflix and prime video were still not working, then I signed all exe and dll of browser and then spotfy started playing but Netflix still doesn’t work. Does anyone have any solution?

heres the args.gn

```
build_with_tflite_lib=false
clang_use_chrome_plugins=false
google_api_key="some"
google_default_client_id="some"
google_default_client_secret="some"
symbol_level=0
treat_warnings_as_errors=false
chrome_pgo_phase=0
ffmpeg_branding="Chrome"
is_clang=true
is_component_build=false
is_debug=false
proprietary_codecs=true
target_cpu="x64"
use_gnome_keyring=false
use_sysroot=false
is_official_build=true
enable_widevine=true 
#disabled bundle_widevine_cdm = true
enable_media_foundation_widevine_cdm = true
```

Comment: Would have been better if you could mention that flags you used to build Chromium

Comment: I have added more details